# How to make the text color different from the input field color

Tags: css, reactjs

I have an input field that changes colors when in dark mode or in light mode.However, I am having trouble keeping the input field border a seperate color than the text. The client wants a very light input field border but the input text to have more of a contrast when the user types. Everytime I change my code the text and border still stay the same color as one another

```js
function App() {
  const [bg, setBg] = React.useState('light');
  const toggleMode = () => {
    setBg((prev) => {
      if (prev === 'light') return 'dark';
      return 'light';
    });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleMode}>Toggle Mode</button>
      <p>Mode is {bg}</p>
      <div className="form-input">
        <div
          className="form-input-title"
          style={{
            fontFamily: "'Lato', sans-serif",
            color: bg === 'light' ? 'black' : '#CBCBCB',
          }}
        >
          Email
        </div>
        <div className="form-input-input">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            style={{
              color: bg === 'light' ? '#DCDCE4' : '#48484D',
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(<App />);
```

```css
.form-input {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 7px 0px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.form-input-title {
  color: #CBCBCB;
  font-size: 14px;
  
  
}

.form-input-input { 
  
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


.form-input input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 41.77px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I updated your code snippet so that it is runnable, but I'm not seeing the behaviour you're describing. ie. I am not seeing "the text and border still stay the same color as one another". Could you please add to it until you reproduce the problem? Here is an online IDE version as well: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-yvfrf6?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply the same color to the input text, border and outline (when focused), you have to set the `border-color`, `color` and `outline` CSS properties:

```
const bg = false;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <input
      style={{
        color: bg ? "red" : "skyblue",
        outline: bg ? "red" : "skyblue",
        borderColor: bg ? "red" : "skyblue"
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Nevertheless, it is **highly recommended** to use a different color for the `outline` for [accessibility purposes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-color#accessibility_concerns). A slightly darker or lighter color than the default text/border color would be a good choice.

You can also use the `border-style: solid` to give your input field a uniform solid color.

---

A more [DRY](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) approach:

```
  const selectedColor = bg ? "red" : "skyblue";

  return (
    <input
      style={{
        color: selectedColor,
        outline: selectedColor,
        borderColor: selectedColor
      }}
    />
  );
```

Comment: Thank you! This answered my question. I ended changing the style of the input to this: color: bg === "light" ? "black" : "#CBCBCB",
                    outline: bg=== "light" ? "#DCDCE4":"#48484D",
                    borderColor: bg=== "light" ? "#DCDCE4":"#48484D",